# Making load and getproeprty methods of java.util.Properties thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am using these statements to load java program properties at runtime.

```
 public static void Init(String confFile) {
        try {
            prop.load(new FileInputStream(confFile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Same class has the following method for reading properties

```
 public static String GetProperty(String key) {
        return prop.getProperty(key);
    }
```

My question is, if I call Init and GetProperty simultaneously without the synchronized block will it cause a problem?

I read this  [java Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) . here it says that the getProperty method is thread safe. yes, I know this, because I have been using it with multiple threads, but now while one thread is **loading** new properties and others are calling the **getProperty** method I think it can cause problems

Comment: your code snippet has no obvious usage of a Properties instance, so it's impossible to say anything meaningful.

Comment: Since all the threads are just reading from the `properties` file, it wont make any difference !!, and also the `Properties` class is thread safe.

Comment: @jtahlborn I have edit the question to make it more clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is threadsafe.

- `Properties` extends `Hashtable`, which is threadsafe.
- Its `load()` methods are synchronized
- Its default properties are also a `Hashtable`

Comment: okay, I am going to believe you for the time being. lets see if I get any issue.